# How can I override flags defined in locust.conf?

Tags: locust

Since by default I want to run my Locust tests in headless mode, I defined the following in my `locust.conf` :

```
headless = true
```

However, I would like to override this in the CLI. But something like

```
locust --headless false
```

doesn't work.

Is there any way to override such flags using the CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most flags that approach works fine. But for some reason `configargparse` has issues with overriding a boolean value to false on command line.

There is a specific (hidden) parameter in Locust called `--headful` to work around this particular issue. It overrides any other headless setting.